# Erro de tradução em: "Flagging -> Esta pergunta não é daqui porque"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Gostaria de informar um erro de tradução no menu de Flag, consta na imagem abaixo:

[image: erro de traducao]

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obs: "Flagging" não deveria ser "Sinalizando" ?

Comment: Traduzido para "Fora de escopo"